# What are the subtle differences between the four sentences about "leave"?

Tags: phrases, synonyms, tenses

> 1. He **leaves** for Japan next week.
> 2. He **is leaving** for Japan next week.
> 3. He **will leave** for Japan next week.
> 4. He **is going to leave** for Japan next week.

Though I know all the four sentences are correct, and interchangeable in most situations. However, I still wonder:

**What are *the subtle differences* between them?**

Comment: Closely related:["going to" vs "will"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/) and [Differences between ways to express future actions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57053/)

Comment: Also related [Is it correct to say "We start tomorrow"? Shouldn't it be "We are starting tomorrow"? (present simple vs continuous for future event)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226650/) and [What’s the difference between "Are you going" and "Will you go"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268302/)