# At this time tomorrow, I am playing cricket

Tags: meaning-in-context, tenses, time, present-tense, future

I know that:

> At this time tomorrow, I will be playing cricket.

is used since the so-called future continuous is used to talk about a continuous activity at a specific time in the future. Even present continuous is used to talk about a planned activity in the future. So my question is can we say this?

> At this time tomorrow, I am playing cricket.

I am eagerly waiting for the scholars' or experts' comments on this.

Comment: At the specified time will you start to play, or be in the middle of a game?

Comment: This is a previous question, well answered by roaring fish:  [Is it correct to say "We start tomorrow"? Shouldn't it be "We are starting tomorrow"? (present simple vs continuous for future event)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226650/is-it-correct-to-say-we-start-tomorrow-shouldnt-it-be-we-are-starting-tomor)

Comment: This question is totally different.This is not about simple present and present continuous but present continuous and future continuous for a specific activity at a particular point in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is correct.

> Want to  meet for a coffee (at) this time tomorrow?
>
> -- Sorry, can't. This time tomorrow I'm taking my dog to the veterinarian.

**at** is optional in conversational English in this instance.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Tim R for answering my question.Most non native speakers of English say that I will be taking my dog to the veterinarian. Even some native speakers have argued with me that I am playing cricket is wrong since it is present continuous. They are surely under the influence of traditional grammarians

Comment: Please don't 'answer' obvious duplicates (when they're already pointed out, they're usually obvious duplicates).

Comment: This is not surely a duplicate

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I also wanted to address **(at) this time tomorrow**.

Comment: @Jvlnarasimharao   *I will be  (I'll be) playing cricket* is not incorrect but they are wrong to insist that **I am playing** is incorrect.

Comment: Preposition deletion with temporal adjuncts has also already been well covered on ELU.

Comment: I totally agree with you. All of us have learned that At this time tomorrow, I will be playing cricket but not I am not playing cricket though it is also is correct. None of the grammar books I have read suggested that present continuous should also be used in the context.Anyhow, I want to reiterate that my question is not atall duplicate and I feel that it shouldn't have been closed. Thank you so much for your comments