# "Timetable future": Why are "I leave at 8 pm" & "I am leaving at 8 pm" OK but not "I eat a pizza at 6 pm" & "I am eating a pizza at 6 pm"?

Tags: present-tense, future

These four sentences have the same meaning (ignoring perhaps some subtleties/nuances):

1. *I will be leaving at 8 pm.*
2. *I will leave at 8 pm.*
3. *I leave at 8 pm.*
4. *I am leaving at 8 pm.*

I understand from "timetable future", "diary future", [Simple Present for Future Actions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/simple-present-for-future-actions) that we can use the present tense as in 3 and 4 above.

But now consider these similar sentences:

5. *I will be eating a pizza at 6 pm.*
6. *I will eat a pizza at 6 pm.*
7. *I eat a pizza at 6 pm.*
8. *I am eating a pizza at 6 pm.*

Why do 7 and 8 sound weird/unnatural/"wrong"? (How/why is 7 different from 3? And how/why is 8 different from 4?)

At [Present tense for future events](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events), the example used was *Our flight leaves tomorrow at 6pm* vs *It rains tomorrow at 6pm*. The explanation given (in all three answers) was this: We use the present tense for future events if we're very certain the event will occur.

But here, I'm as certain of eating a pizza at 6 pm as I am of leaving at 8 pm.

And, my plan to eat a pizza at 6 pm is as formally and rigidly scheduled as my plan to leave at 8 pm.

---

**This Q is not a duplicate.** This Q is not about present simple vs present continuous.

Instead, it's about why some specific actions such as *leaving* allow for "timetable future" (present simple to show a one-off action in the future), while others don't.

Above I used the example *eating a pizza*. But consider instead this perhaps clearer example:

7. *I amputate my left leg at 6 pm.*
8. *I am amputating my left leg at 6 pm.*

Again, 7 and 8 sound weirder than 3 and 4. Why?

*Amputating my left leg* is at least as one-off, certain, formally and rigidly scheduled, non-regular, and non-repeated as *leaving*. So why can't I also use "timetable future" here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to say "We start tomorrow"? Shouldn't it be "We are starting tomorrow"? (present simple vs continuous for future event)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226650/is-it-correct-to-say-we-start-tomorrow-shouldnt-it-be-we-are-starting-tomor) Roaring Fish: 'Using present continuous as in "I am buying a new car." **This is usually used for [formal] arrangements**.

Using present simple, as in "I get my new car this afternoon!" **This is usually used for things that are scheduled / on a [rigid] timetable**.' I'd add '**and not otherwise**.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I added this at the end: *my plan to eat a pizza at 6 pm is as formally and rigidly scheduled as my plan to leave at 8 pm.*

Comment: (7) and (8) _would_ be used when formal structuring _is_ in place ('**I'm** not going to watch the match! I [always] eat a pizza at 6 pm.' / 'I've the list of activities I have to stick to during the monitored experiment ... I'm eating a pizza at 6 pm [, for instance].') The weirdness comes from the fact that these contrived examples so rarely occur. If you're just planning to eat around 6 pm and intend to have pizza, that's **not** formal structuring.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Why is *I eat a pizza at 6 pm* automatically interpreted as something that occurs regularly (and so is considered weird)---but the same is not true of *I leave at 8 pm*?

Answer (score 6):

It is not the grammar that makes these sentences sound strange it is the actual meaning.

- I eat a pizza at 6 pm.

This  means that you do so always, regularly, habitually. It sounds strange because to eat a pizza at 6pm as a regular habit sounds strange. If, instead, you said, 'I have my dinner at 6pm', that would not sound strange.

- I am eating a pizza at 6 pm.

This means that it is your intention to be in the act of eating a pizza at 6pm. Again it is not the grammar but the meaning of the words that makes this sound strange. Not using the contraction 'I'm' makes it sound even stranger as it makes it sound inappropriately formal for a statement about pizza. If you said, "I'm having a few beers at 6pm" this construction wouldn't sound strange.

Why would you be telling somebody of your intention to be engaged in the act of eating a pizza at a specific time?

There are some possibilities:

A: Will you join us for a hamburger? We're meeting at 7pm.
B: I'd love to but I'm eating a pizza at 6 pm. I promised the kids.

A: How is the diet?
B: I finished it yesterday. I can't wait to get off work.  I'm eating a pizza at 6 pm with Mary then we're going to the movies at 8.00 and I'm having popcorn and sodas, then we're hitting a nightclub for cocktails.

Comment: Why can't the same arguments be applied to "I leave at 8pm"? E.g. *This means that you do so always, regularly, habitually. It sounds strange because to [leave at 8 pm] as a regular habit sounds strange.*